# How do you make page templates load based on a page's entire url not just their slug?

Tags: wordpress, templates

How do you make page templates load based on a page's entire url not just their slug?

Page templates load either `page-{slug}.php` or `page-{id}.php`.

I really want it to load `page-{parent-slug}_{slug}.php`.

So the url `/hello/world` would look for the template `page-hello_world.php`.

This should be recursive so the longer the page url the longer template filename.

There is no **template_redirect** documentation in the API.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you search on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @ThunderRabbit I sure did, Google, and wordpress.org. Help me SO you're my only hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It works great and added it to the functions.php file in the theme's folder:

```
function hierarchical_template() {
    global $post;       
    $permalink_array =
        array_filter(explode('/',str_replace(get_site_url(),'',get_permalink($post->ID))));     
    $template_redirect = false;     
    while ( count( $permalink_array ) ) {           
        $template = 'page-' . implode( '_', $permalink_array ) . '.php';            
        if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template)){
            include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template);
            exit;               
        }           
        array_shift($permalink_array);
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'hierarchical_template');
```

Comment: Oooooh, I like this. Also a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your page.php file, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
get_header();

$ancestors = get_ancestors(get_the_ID(), 'page');
$current_page = get_page(get_the_ID());
$top_page = $ancestors ? get_page(end($ancestors)) : false;
if($top_page && $file = locate_template('page-'.$top_page->post_name.'_'.$current_page->post_name.'.php'))
{
    include $file;
}
else if($file = locate_template('page-'.$current_page->post_name.'.php'))
{
    include $file;
}
else
{
    //DEFAULT HTML TO DISPLAY
}
?>
```

This is untested, but the idea is for your page.php to search for and include a matching 'page-{parent-slug}_{slug}.php' file. If it can't find the matching file, then it will search for 'page-{slug}.php'. If that doesn't exist, then it will fall back on the default HTML in the else statement.

Hope this helps.